# Connecting a TV remote control to a Windows 7 Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, tv, remote-control

I was just wondering how possible it is to connect a remote control to a Windows 7 system.

I’m connecting the computer to a 24" TV via HDMI to be used as a TV, playing things mainly through VLC.

Clearly I don’t want to have to access the PC every time I want to change something. The problem is that I have no idea how to configure a remote to a PC, or even what remote will do the job.

I’m not looking for anything overly flashy or in the $100-$200 range, but something that is functional and will get the job done.